Fresh install of drupal 10/11 all pages 404
I've installed drupal 10 and 11 via composer and by downloading the zip file and running the installer. By the time I get to my home page everything looks fine on drupal 10, the static resources dont load on drupal 11. Then every page I try to access results in a 404. I don't know if clean urls are enabled because I cannot get to the admin page. I can see the .htaccess file but there's not much going on in there. After 4 different installations of drupal I am stumped. I am running the following:
MAMP with PHP 8.3.9
Drupal 10 https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/10.0.0
Drupal 11 https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/11.0.1
drupal 10 installed with composer

drupal 10 install via web ui

404 on every page except home page

404 everywhere

.htaccess file drupal 10 and 11, installed via composer and via ui same content
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>

Drupal 11:

Warnings that I always get during gui installs:


LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
The above line was commented out in my httpd.conf for MAMP
